# Конкурентный доступ к кортежу в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

Есть таблица с счетом, на которую наваливается сразу много запросов, которые списывают с него средства:

```
create table account
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    volume BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

update account
set volume = volume - 10
where id = 1 and volume > 10;
```

Как можно средствами SQL гарантировать что утечки данных при `update` не будет.

Как я понимаю, если повышать уровень изоляции, то это только усугубит проблему, так как актуальность данных при чтении еще уменьшится. Но конкурентный доступ нужно обеспечить. Что для этого нужно сделать и почему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не нужно делать. На любом уровне изоляции транзакций у вас нет риска аномалий конкурентного обновления данных *одной и той же строки*.

Запросы

```
update account
set volume = volume - 10
where id = 1 and volume > 10;
```

Замечательно сериализуются самой СУБД на ожидании row-level блокировки строки. postgresql выполняет update всегда над самой актуальной версией подходящей по условию строки.

---

Проблема у вас будет, если вы попытаетесь расчёт нового volume вынести на приложение:

```
begin;
select volume from account where id = ?;
-- некоторая логика на приложении
update account set volume = ? where id = ?;
commit;
```

Здесь race condition есть.